# Discord.py how do I get a username in a mongoDB leaderboard command?

Tags: python, mongodb, discord.py, leaderboard, pymongo-3.x

So I made a Discord.py leaderboard command with MongoDB, everything works but I can't send the users name.

Data is stored like this:

```
_id: 484363190168322049 #users id
experience: 964
level: 5
```

Python code:

```
@client.command(aliases = ["et", "leaderboard"])
async def lb(ctx, arg=10):
    rankings = collection.find().sort("experience",-1)
    i=1
    embed = discord.Embed(title = f"***Top {arg} users***")
    for x in rankings:
        print(x["_id"])
        user = client.get_user(x["_id"])
        user_xp = x["experience"]
        ##########################################################################
        # This is where I want to add the user username instead of <@{x['_id']}> #
        ##########################################################################
        embed.add_field(name=f"{i}: <@{x['_id']}>", value=f"XP │ {user_xp}", inline=False)
        if i == arg:
            break
        else:
            i += 1
    embed.set_footer(text=f"{ctx.guild}", icon_url=f"{ctx.guild.icon_url}")
    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

This mentions the user but I don't want that, I want only want the user's username,
I have tried:

```
user = client.get_user(x["_id"])
embed.add_field(name=f"{i}: {user.name}>", value=f"XP │ {user_xp}", inline=False)
```

Previously this has worked with my other commands, but it returns:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the bot doesn't fetch the user (NoneType error). Try to do this:

```
user1 = int(x["_id"])
user = client.get_user(user1) 
embed.add_field(name=f"{i}: {user.name}>", value=f"XP │ {user_xp}", inline=False)
```

Or check the database, the error could be the above or it can be a database find() error.

Comment: It prints out all the IDs fine but still gives the same error

Comment: try print(user)

Comment: and if it doesn't work try client.fetch_user() instead of get_user()

Comment: Thanks client.fetch_user() worked for me!

Comment: The error was probably that the user was not into a server with the bot, in this case fetch_user is useful. Happy to help you!